# Linking a facebook app's page to an existing facebook business page

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app page, and a separate facebook business profile page.

The business page was created, but not by me, some time before the app and its page were created. **Is there any way to connect the two pages, or import the content and friends from one to the other**?

The older profile page has some content; a set of friends and wall posts that I don't want to lose. It was created before I had a chance to set up an app page. Since the app was created more recently, it does not have any content posted to it.

I intended the app page to eventually hold some advertising info for my main website itself (non-canvas, just using fb for the connect api etc). The idea being that as people sign up on my site through facebook's OAuth, I could use the graph api to post to their wall.

The wall posts are working as expected but naturally they are directing users to the facebook app page, which has no content, friends etc. I'd prefer to be directed to the original business page, where the party is really happening.

Now it seems that the two pages are completely separate; what would I need to do to direct the users to the business page?

Comment: I saw that you have a great answer by Piers, has that worked for you yet?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is post an update to the users of the page saying that it's closing and that they should join the new page. You might lose some of them, but not all. I guess you could download the data from that page via the graph API so you have a record, and whilst you would be able to re-post them, they obviously wouldn't be from the original users.

It might be worth emailing Facebook support to see if they might possible combine the groups, but considering that if they did it once they'd be setting a precedent so I doubt they will, but there's no harm in it.

Otherwise, I suggest doing what I said in the first paragraph and hoping that the users move over.